# Генерация диалога с помощью цепей Маркова (Python)

Tags: python, генераторы

Хочу генерировать осмысленный диалог с помощью цепей Маркова. Пытался использовать библиотеку `markovify`, но смысла в генерируемых диалогах нет. Подскажите, можно как то сгенерировать диалог со смыслом или, может быть, для этих целей лучше подойдут нейросети?

```
import markovify

with open("test.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
text_model = markovify.Text(text)
for i in range(4):
    print(text_model.make_short_sentence(270))
```

Comment: Покажите код, который у вас уже есть с цепью маркова. Интересно посмотреть.

Comment: `import markovify
with open("test.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
 text = f.read()
text_model = markovify.Text(text)
for i in range(4):
 print(text_model.make_short_sentence(270))`

Comment: "но смысла в генерируемых диалогах нет" - а с чего там должен быть смысл? Это же просто генерирование случайных фраз на основе загруженного текста. Для действительно осмысленных диалогов вам нужен сильный искусственный интеллект (которого на данный момент не существует), а не цепи Маркова. Либо естественный интеллект (например, можно нанять живого копирайтера, он вам напишет осмысленный диалог).

Answer (score 0):

Как то вы все упростили до тривиальности.

Вот тут  - введение в ответ на ваш вопрос. Уже изучили?

https://datascienceplus.com/natural-language-generation-with-markovify-in-python/

А вообще генерация осмысленного текста, да еще и осмысленногго диалога - задача нетривиальная по своей сути. Если подходить к ней серьезно.